# Loading XML into WCF and parse the information into WCF Client application

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

What I have been trying to do is to load any XML file and pass that as a parameter using POST and HTTP. The problem am having is that, I can't get the response either in client side or even when I browse locally to Service1.svc/XMLTest. My code is as follow: 
service.svc:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace XMLService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 :IService1 
    {
        public string XMLTest(Stream XMLParam)
        {  
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml("D:\\test.xml");
            return xDoc.OuterXml;

        }
    }
}
```

Iservice1.cs

```
namespace XMLService
{// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]

    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "XMLTest")]
        string XMLTest(Stream XMLParam)

    }
}
```

Web Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="XMLService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Default" >
        <endpoint address ="" contract="XMLService.IService1" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client side Asp.Net page where I make a call to the WCF Using "Post" and "HTTP"

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:23457/Service1.svc/XMLTest");
            request.Method = "POST";  // Set the Method property of the request to POST.

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest and Length
            request.ContentType = "application / x - www - form - urlencoded"; //"text/xml";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            //Load the XML Document
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml("D:\\test.xml");
            string rawXml = xDoc.OuterXml;

            // Get the request stream, write the data to the request stream
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            //Web Response, display the status, 
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream 
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close(); 

        }
```

Comment: Please ask a question. Just stating: "I couldn't load the xml, save it locally and call that url in the client WCF" is too unspecific.

Comment: How is the class `Service` used in your example? Also, do not use `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]`, use `[WebGet]` instead.

Comment: @carlosfigueira, I used the service as  Public class Sevice: Iservice I also changed WebInvoke to WebGet but still not loading the XML

Comment: Your class `Service` is defined as a data contract, and doesn't implement `IService` (look at your question). Please post a [small, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) in your question and you will get better answers.

Comment: @carlosfigueira, Thank you for your help. I am still trying to get it work. I have provided a better post, hope you will be able to assist me. Thanks!

Comment: `"I can't get the response either in client side"` - what do you mean? What error do you get? `"or even when I browse locally to Service1.svc/XMLTest"` - browsing won't work (it issues a `GET` request, and the operation responds to `POST` requests).

Comment: @carlosfigueira I was getting run time error, I have figured it out. Thank You!

Comment: In this case please post the solution to your problem as an answer (and accept it) so that other people can learn from your mistake as well. Thanks!